# Microsoft Graph Api - Searching ONLY inside a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I have been trying to perform a search query on the Microsoft Graph API, to find driveItems inside a given folder. The problem is, the search is returning results outside the given folder, much earlier in the folder hierarchy - this is a problem, since I don't want my app to have access to anything that is not inside the folder.

So, example folder structure:

```
ParentFolder
-- A.pdf
-- B.pdf
-- ChildFolder
   -- C.pdf
```

According to the graph API documentation, a folder is identified by their driveItemID, inside a given drive. Sure enough, performing a GET to

```
/drives/"driveID"/items/"ChildFolderID"
```

works wonders - I can find the folder and all of its information, and the /children lists only C.pdf.

However, the search functionality does not seem to be scoped correctly.
Performing `/drives/<driveID>/items/ChildFolderID/search(q='pdf')` is returning any PDF file inside my whole drive, and not just inside ChildFolder.
The same is true if I substitute the /drives/driveID part by simply /me/drive, which is a reference to the one drive business "my files" drive.

Below is my code, using the [msgraph-sdk-javascript](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) sdk to perform the get request (this is just an example, the problem cannot be with the sdk itself, since using the graph explorer tool the same issue occurs).

```
            let url = `/drives/${driveID}/items/${itemID}/search(q='${query}')?`;

            if (options.cursor)
                url += `$skiptoken=${options.cursor}`;

            return self.client
                .api(url)
                .top(options.limit)
                .headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }).get()
                .then(data => {

                    console.log('data: ', data);
                    // ... rest of function ...
```

That data object has all my pdf files: A.pdf, B.pdf and C.pdf.

What baffles me the most is that the request is working perfectly inside a sharepoint instance. Requesting `/sites/siteID/drives/driveID/items/ChildFolder/search(q='pdf')` is correctly scoping the search to only search inside the given folder. And it is the same API.
Edit: nevermind Sharepoint also doesn't work, same problem.

Comment: update:
now instead of returning results from outside the folder, the API has decided to start returning an empty result set. The request is successful, just no results.

So, searching for "pdf" returns empty even when I have plenty of pdf files inside the given folder, same thing with folder names, file names, etc